# How to set image in default alert dialog without using custom view in android

Tags: android, android-dialog

How to set image in default alert dialog without using custom view in android.Is it possible to set image in default alert diaog ?

Thanks

Comment: Here you want to added image in alert diaog? Write more detail in question.

Answer (score 0):

We use this to set a custom icon in Alert Dialog.

```
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon);
```